# get ID of a textview that i clicked

Tags: android

i have a lot of textviews in my app i want to create a method and set it on the onClick in all the textviews  Xml, so when i click on a textview it should get me the text of that textview.
this is my methode:

```
 public void getnum(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello  ", 5).show();
//need to add something here to get the text of the textview that i clicked;}
```

this is the Xml:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Numero1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="getnum"
    android:text="Numero1" />
```

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to get the text in the `TextView`, or the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text of the clicked `TextView` you can use the `getText()` method:

```
public void getnum(View v){
    TextView clickedTextView = (TextView) v;
    String text = clickedTextView.getText().toString();
}
```

The `View` passed in parameter is the clicked `View`, in your case is one of your `TextView`s.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be giving each TextView a tag (android:tag="1"), then in the on click method, call v.getTag(). You cal also access the text of the TextView in that method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the view to a TextView and use that get the text.

```
public void getnum(View v){
    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
    String text = tv.getText().toString();
}
```